# Using =SPLIT and converting whole number to decimal percent

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PvWF7futRjBkq6_iV4qnjjMmfnRUlysMdf0hEjWjUis/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to simplify my spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that imports data from a table on a website.  Sometimes this data is a percentage in decimal format, and sometimes the website doesn't have precise data, so it gives two numbers.  For example, "7-13%".  I use =SPLIT to separate these two numbers into Columns D & E, then in Column F, I convert them to decimal percent and average them.  This percentage is then multiplied by the contents of Column B

Is there a simpler way to do this, and compress it down into one column instead of three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("–", C3)), (B3*sum(split(C3,"–%"))/2)*0.01, B3*C3)
```

Seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"(\d+)-(\d+)%"))/200*B3
```

If data occasionally comes as single digits without "-", Try this:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"(\d+)-(\d+)%"))/200*B3,C3*B3)
```